# How to use Modifier.contentSize in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation

```
If you are animating changes to content size:
Use Modifier.contentSize.
```

However, I cannot find how to access `Modifier.contentSize` and use it. Any guide?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are talking about the **animateContentSize** function.

Here I have an example that might help

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
            // This `Column` animates its size when its content changes.
            .animateContentSize()
    ) {
        Row {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Info,
                contentDescription = null
            )
            // ...
        }
        if (expanded) { // If the expanded value is changed then the animateContentSize will be triggered
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.lorem_ipsum),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
            )
        }
    }
```

[image]

From the Jetpack Compose [Animation codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-animation?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-animation#4):

Comment: Nice. Looks like it's a typo in the document.